# Mysql table is full with enough disk space

Tags: mysql, linux, virtualbox

I get a "General error: 1114 The table ‘article’ is full" during a request which alters a ~300k lines table.

The request:
`ALTER TABLE article ADD intId INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ADD categoryIntId INT DEFAULT NULL, ADD sourceIntId INT DEFAULT NULL`

I have free disk space:
`Filesystem Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0  29G   17G   11G  61% /`

no max in innodb_data_file_path
`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_data_file_path';
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name         | Value                  |
+-----------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_data_file_path | ibdata1:12M:autoextend |
+-----------------------+------------------------+`

table size 8.4G
`ls -lh /var/lib/mysql/article/article.ibd
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 8.4G Jan 15 11:50 /var/lib/mysql/article/article.ibd`

/var/lib/mysql is not on a different mount point than /
`df -h
Filesystem Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/dm-0  29G   17G   11G  61% /
udev       10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs      793M   81M  713M  11% /run
tmpfs      2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs      5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs      2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1  226M   33M  181M  16% /boot`

This is in a Virtual BOX vm. The host machine has 3G left of disk space but that should not impact the VM ?

I've search this page without success: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html

Comment: I would not assume your VM has access to all of your machine's free disk space. I would check for limits there.

Comment: ALTER TABLE commands uses disk space... https://serverfault.com/questions/277696/how-much-disk-space-does-innodb-need-to-alter-table